# What is the VBA (EXCEL) Code for backing to the userform page?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am writing a VBA program to read a workbook from computer:

```
Private Sub btnOpenWkbook_Click()

Dim strWkbookPath As String

strWkbookPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel file, *.xlsx")

Workbooks.Open Filename:=strWkbookPath

Set Swkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strWkbookPath)

...

...

If strWkbookPath = "False" Then
   Unload frmSalesReport
End If

end sub
```

[image]

Click the "open workbook" then a  Open dialog box opened:
[image: Open dialog box]

> If the user clicks the Cancel button or Close button on the Open dialog box, how to back to the userform page?

Now I get this error:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub btnOpenWkbook_Click()
Dim strWkbookPath As String
strWkbookPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel file, *.xlsx")
If strWkbookPath = "" Or strWkbookPath = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strWkbookPath
Set Swkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strWkbookPath)
'...
'...
'If strWkbookPath = "False" Then
'   Unload frmSalesReport
'End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to watch your value of `strWkbookPath`. And you'll know what you should do.